# Не получается загрузить (установить) VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Начал изучать `Vue`, когда дело дошло до `Vux` и `Vue Router` начались проблемы.

Не получается установить `vuex`, терминал (PowerShell) выдает предупреждения о том, что не хватает какого-то файла. Не могу понять что за `package.json` файл он от меня требует.

Cкрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Файл [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) в том числе нужен для того что бы контролировать зависимости Вашего проекта. Именно это и хочет сделать Vuex, добавив себя в этот список.

Проинициализируйте Ваш проект, выполнив в терминале команду:

```
npm init
```

Это запустит [wizard](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file), который поможет Вам сконфигурировать и создать package.json

Comment: Спасибо, помогла команда - npm init --yes